# Find the empty classrooms in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i cant wrap my mind around this problem apparently. So, i'm using 2 tables like this :
Table Classrooms:

```
CLASSROOMS
----------
Num | Type
__________
1   |'Normal'
2   |'Normal'
3   |'Normal'
1   |'Lab'
2   |'Lab'
```

Table Classes:

```
CLASSES
-------------------------
s_h  | f_h | num | type
_________________________
8:30 |10:30| 1   | 'Normal'
8:30 |10:30| 1   | 'Lab'
8:30 |10:30| 2   | 'Normal'
10:30|12:30| 1   | 'Normal'
12:30|14:30| 2   | 'Lab'
```

I basically want to reserve a classroom by inserting a row in the 2nd table.the insertion should be performed via procedure. this procedure given the starting and ending time of preference should look basically for an empty classroom and if there aren't any return a table of any available time for each class.
Now, assuming that there isn't a time_scheduling that determine the format nor lenght of the classes and i only know that the school has an opening and a closing time, how can i find such a result set ? Let's look at an example to clarify what i'm trying to achieve. Consider the simplest example. Two classrooms of the same type.

```
CLASSROOMS
----------
Num | Type
__________
1   |'Normal'
2   |'Normal'
```

Let's consider further that the first classroom is occupied from 10:00 to 13:00 and the second is from 9:00 to 13:00, the first one has three classes of 1 hour each and the second one has two of two hours. We will therfore have a table that look like this :

Table Classes:

```
CLASSES
-------------------------
s_h  | f_h | num | type
_________________________
10:00|11:00| 1   | 'Normal'
11:00|12:00| 1   | 'Normal'
12:00|13:00| 1   | 'Normal'
09:00|11:00| 2   | 'Normal'
11:00|13:00| 2   | 'Normal'
```

Now, from this table i want to construct a table that tells me basically when each class is free to book. in this case essentially something like this :
(there can be an easier way, i'm not sure)

```
FREE
    -----------------------------
    s_h  | f_h | num | type
    _____________________________
     08:00|10:00| 1   | 'normal'
     13:00|14:00| 1   | 'normal'
      8:00|09:00| 2   | 'normal'
     13:00|14:00| 2   | 'normal'
```

how can i obtain such result ?

my only tough so far was to create a table of every possible time, and then do something like classes minus this table but of course it wont work first because i should convert every lesson in multiple rows based on how much precise i want the result to be, and second because this second table will result too big. So basically the most naive solution there is.
So well... 2 pennys for your toughts.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a `@DATEDIFF` with time; `JOIN` all the tables and `@DATEDIFF` between `s_h` and `f_h` not equal to 0 then classroom should be available.

Comment: it's a very vague answer, can you please expose your idea further ?

Comment: This scheduling problem is actually pretty hard to solve in SQL, because SQL works with rows and scheduling works with a grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now this works. First insert rows into classes table specifying open and close times of classes

```
insert into classes
select '' as s_h,'08:00:00' as f_h, num, type from classrooms
union
select '14:00:00' as s_h,'' as f_h, num, type from classrooms;
```

After this I'm using `row_number() over (partition by num order by s_h)` which ranks the classes by start time for each classroom. This will look like this

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by num order by s_h) as rn from classes
```

Using the same query twice and joining one row of first table (sub query) to next row of second table (same query) `a.rn=b.rn-1` on num gives me a sequence of classes. Like one class is followed by other class. Now I'm eliminating classes which are continuous by writing where clause `where a.f_h!=b.s_h`

```
select a.num,a.f_h, b.s_h from
  (select *, row_number() over (partition by num order by s_h) as rn from classes) as a
  join
  (select *, row_number() over (partition by num order by s_h) as rn from classes) as b
on a.num=b.num and a.rn=b.rn-1
where a.f_h!=b.s_h
```

In between is just an explanation, use insert query and above query, you should be good with that. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51fe3/12

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: ok, this honestly looks too difficult to get, i really need further help understand what you're doing, thank you.

Comment: let me know when you have the time @Avinash

Comment: Sorry, I checked this again.. It doesn't work for more than 2 consecutive classes.. I'll try to come up with something else

Comment: @darkpirate, updated answer, now it works. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: unfortunatly the sqlfiddle link doesn't work :( that's quite an interesting idea to try. i will try it out tomorrow for sure mate :) ty vm